# Replace css if mobile/tablet

Tags: php, css, mobile, replace, detection

I am using Mobile detect and i want to remove my custom.css when a mobile or tablet is browsing the site.

Can enyone explain what i am doing wrong ?

```
<?php 

// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once 'php/mobile_detect.php';

$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if ($detect-&gt;isMobile()) {$mobile = '1';}

if ($mobile == 1) {

    echo '<link href="'.$site.'css/mobile.css'" rel="stylesheet">';
}else {
    echo '<link href="'.$site.'css/desktop.css'" rel="stylesheet">';
    }

?>
```

Comment: What is/not happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
if ($detect-&gt;isMobile()) {$mobile = '1';}
```

With

```
if ($detect->isMobile()) {$mobile = '1';}
```

See if that works

Comment: Yes that works! Cool Thank you.

But now i am getting this error 

Undefined variable: mobile in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 10

Call Stack

1 0.0007 271704 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0

line 10 is this `if ($mobile == 1) {`

Comment: Ok, if i run it online and not whit wamp, i dot get the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with mismatched quotes as well as with your `-&gt`. Try

```
if ($detect->isMobile()) {$mobile = '1';}
```

instead

With your mismatched quotes, use

```
echo '<link href="'+$site+'css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet">';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did and it works.

```
// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once 'php/mobile_detect.php';

$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if ($detect->isMobile()) {$mobile = '1';}

if ($mobile == 1) {
    echo '<link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet">';
}else {
    echo '<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">';
    }

?>
```